# Sum of subset converges to an irrational

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that $a_n>0$ for all $n$ and $\displaystyle \sum \limits _{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

Is it true that there exists some irrational number $0<\alpha <L$ and a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ such that $\displaystyle \sum \limits _{k=1}^\infty a_{n_k}=\alpha$?

Can we generalise this result and say that we can find such a subsequence for every number $0<\alpha <L$ large enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note all $a_n>0$. Since $\sum a_n$ is convergent, one can find a subsequence which for convenience we denote also by $a_n$, so that for every $n$ we have
$$
a_n > a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+...
$$
This (sub)sequence has the property that any two different subsequences of it have different sums! (An example of this kind of sequence: $1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, ...$ ). Now since there are uncountably many (sub)subsequences, there must be one whose sum is an irrational number.

In general, the set of sums of all subsequences can have some gaps.